# Using React anonymous functional component to render to screen

Tags: reactjs, components

Hello I have a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hy8cuvfg/

html

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  {()=><p>hello world!</p>},
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I am trying to output 'hello world!'. I want to make this work using an anonymous functional component:

```
()=><p>hello world!</p>
```

How should I fix this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

ESLint and Airbnb would give warming for it anyway here you have it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o1tzhd

Goodluck

Comment: So it is not possible to pass anonymous functional component in the same js file as render() is called?

Comment: nope that's not possible, the closed you can get to is having it in another component, thats the only answer you gonna get  don't waste your time reseraching